# Video tag error

Tags: html, html5-video

in my html page i want to add a video in to it and i have tried multiple times adding in and deleting stuff in this code.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

i have also tried.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

and

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

^^^^
that with diffrent formats.
the error i get is this
[image]

and it dosent play anything.
i have triple checked i have the names right and i have the video in the same place as my html document.

Answer (score 0):

Code seesm okay.
Make sure :
1) Your browser supports HTML5.
2) http://caniuse.com/#search=video - this is a link to check whether your browser supports video tag or not.

3) take special considerations for your .mp4 format. It is simply due to codec mismatch. When i needed to do it for my office, i tried coouple of .mp4 files (thought the extension is same, html5 needs MPEG-4/H.264)

Comment: went through what you said. but you may be right on "3)" but how would i change my codec